# Organize divs to 2 columns - css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i have 10 divs one after the other that I want to organize in 2 columns. The thing is that if I float them all I get these columns:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

but instead I want to get these columns:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

is this can be achieved by css only? if not, what is the most efficient jquery that can do this? (I don't  want to touch the markup because it is generated by a complex system...)

the markup is simple:

```
<div class="item">
...
</div>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
...
```

Comment: It can be done. I don't think IE will ever understand this. Alternatively, you could use presentational HTML - then it's easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `column-count` and `column-gap` CSS properties. Both Mozilla and Webkit need prefixes, IE10 and Opera don't. However, IE<=9 does not support that at all.

Something like

```
.item-parent{
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /*...*/
}
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html
http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Alternatively, to support IE9, you could just wrap the two columns manually and style appropriately. If you don't want to dive into the generator - a templating system should have solved that - you can use Javascript:

```
$('.item-parent').each(function(){
  $items = $('.item', this);
  $items.slice(0, ($items.length+1)/2) //split in half, round up
    .wrapAll('<div class="item-column">');
  $items.slice(($items.length+1)/2)
    .wrapAll('<div class="item-column">');
)};
```

Comment: It didn't work. You meant to wrap a div around the first 5 divs, right? i don't think that's what your code does. It wraps a div around each div...

Comment: @MosheShaham fixed, thanks. I keep confusing `wrap` and `wrapAll`

Answer (score 1):

Put the items you have in two DIVs like the followings

```
<style>
.col{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
</style>

<div class="col">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

comes from your complex system (not sure what you actually want to say), you will have to see how these `div` are being generated, and I guess, there wil be very minor change in code to get you desired results

atlternatively, you can use loop to get your required structure..

Comment: I assume `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` is what the complex system produces.

Comment: yes, the system produces the divs in a specific order. so you are saying the best approach is diving into the system and changing the markup?

Comment: @MosheShaham you can change the markup from javascript. Hold on.